# Category List Dropdown padding

Tags: magento2, category

[image]

Our client wants customize category list drop down menu.
So our requirement is to reduce it's height when drop down is opened.

Theme is inherit from Magento blank.

Let me know which file i need to edit.

Comment: You can do this via CSS. You need to give proper height with scroll bar properly.http://jsfiddle.net/vVJGD/8/

Comment: Thanks Piyush.

But how it will affect for responsive.

Comment: That is depend on how you hve displayed menu and sub-menu.

Comment: in responsive, i want 3rd tab when user tap on menu icon.